# React Native, expo

Tags: android, react-native

Estoy intentando abrir un proyecto creado con expo en Android Studio. He sacado el proyecto de expo con el comando `exp detach` y he abierto el proyecto con Android Studio y el Gradle se completa y no aparece ningún error. Abro un emulador y ejecuto en la consola en el directorio del proyecto react-native run-android y esto es lo que aparece:

```
Consola 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 8.906 secs
Running adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Starting the app on emulator-5554 (adb -s emulator-5554 shell am start -n io.gergeml.beatlove/.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=io.gergeml.beatlove/.MainActivity }
```

Y este otro error:

> Could not load expd592adb......... ://localhost:80. Are you sureXDE or
>   exp is running?

Comment: Quita la imagen y copia el error en texto, por favor.

Comment: Emulador: Could not load expd592adb......... ://localhost:80. Are you sureXDE or exp is running?